# Is there any way to check message sent successfully from UIActivityViewController swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am trying to verify that the message I sent using UIActivityViewController is sent successfully or not?

```
        let message = ["This is message which I want check is successfully sent or not"]
    let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: message, applicationActivities: nil)
    ac.completionWithItemsHandler = {activity, success, items, error in
        print(activity)
        print(success)
        print(items)
        print(error)
    }
    present(ac, animated: true)
```

Comment: Aren't you getting success as `true `here, what's the issue?

Comment: @RTXGamer yes I am getting success as true but it does not verify that the message is successfully sent or failed. I want to check that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "verify"? .. success means the message is successfully sent or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are asking is not possible.

The activity indicator will only tell you the following:

- What option the user selected
- Did the user complete the sharing operation (eg. Did he actually send a message)

You will not be able to know if the message was edited before being sent. The most you can do is check if the user at least selected the Message option and not, for example, the Copy option.